# Automatically delete items from multiple lists at once

Tags: python

I currently have a small problem with the processing of some data that I recover.
I'm getting data that's constantly changing and it's displayed as a list like this:

```
[['test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], ['test', 'test', 'test', ' test']]
```

I would like to know how it is possible to automatically delete the second element of each list given that the number of lists can vary depending on the result of the query and that its value can also vary.

Comment: What do you mean by _"**automatically** delete"_? Do you want a piece of code that does that job? Try `data = [part[:1] + part[2:] for part in data]` with `data` your list.

Comment: @Timus Hi, thanks for your answer it's exactly what I needed for now 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could either use .pop(index) or del arr[index]. But since you said it can vary I would use len(arr) to make sure the arr length goes up to the index you are trying to delete

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer I was trying with these functions but I could not automate if the number of elements change however the person above allowed me to solve the problem thanks to you